# View full program command line arguments in OOM killer logs

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, oom-killer

Is it possible to view full program command line arguments in OOM killler logs ?
What I see now in /var/log/syslog is

```
Memory cgroup out of memory: Kill process 29187 (beam.smp) score 998 or sacrifice child
Killed process 29302 (cpu_sup) total-vm:4300kB, anon-rss:76kB, file-rss:272kB
beam.smp invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0xd0, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
beam.smp cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0-3
```

I have plenty of beam.smp processes on my machine and it's not very convenient to find out what particular process was killed by OOM killer.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/oom_dump_tasks
```

which seems about the max that you can get the kernel to display on out-of-memory errors.

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt

> Enables a system-wide task dump (excluding kernel threads) to be
>   produced when the kernel performs an OOM-killing and includes such
>   information as pid, uid, tgid, vm size, rss, nr_ptes, swapents,
>   oom_score_adj score, and name.  This is helpful to determine why the
>   OOM killer was invoked, to identify the rogue task that caused it, and
>   to determine why the OOM killer chose the task it did to kill.
>
> If this is set to zero, this information is suppressed.  On very large
>   systems with thousands of tasks it may not be feasible to dump the
>   memory state information for each one.  Such systems should not be
>   forced to incur a performance penalty in OOM conditions when the
>   information may not be desired.
>
> If this is set to non-zero, this information is shown whenever the OOM
>   killer actually kills a memory-hogging task.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/oom_dump_tasks
```

did not help me much - there're still no command line parameters in the log.
to retrospectively view command line of killed process, you can use [atop](http://linux.die.net/man/1/atop) to record system activity.
if oom-killer kills s/th, just open atop log for that time, find you process by PID from /var/log/syslog, and hit 'c' key to view command line of the process.